# How to write an SQL query to have alternating pattern between rows (like -1 and 1)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I cannot get an alternating pattern of 1 an -1 with my database.

This explains what I am trying to do.

```
ID  Purpose  Date      Val 
1   Derp     4/1/1969   1
1   Derp     4/1/1969  -1
2   Derp     4/2/2011   1
2   Derp     4/2/2011  -1
```

From a database that is something like

```
ID  Purpose  Date      
1   Derp     4/1/1969  
1   Herp     4/1/1911  
2   Woot     4/2/1311  
2   Wall     4/2/211
```

Here is my attempt:

```
SELECT 
     ID 
     ,Purpose 
     ,Date
     ,Val as 1 
FROM (
     SELECT FIRST(Purpose) 
     FROM DerpTable WHERE Purpose LIKE '%DERP%' 
     GROUP BY ID, DATE) as HerpTable, DerpTable 
 WHERE HerpTable.ID = DerpTable.ID AND DerpTable.ID = HerpTable.ID
```

This query does not work for me because my mssm does not recognize 'FIRST' or 'FIRST_VALUE' as built in functions. Thus, I have no way of numbering the first incident of derp and giving it a value.

Problems:

- I am using sql2012 and thus cannot use First.
- I tried using last_value and first_value as seen [here](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2012/07/sql-server-2012-first-value-last-value.html) but get errors indicating that function is not found
- A bunch of sql queries. I've been staring at the MSDN T-SQL help pages
- This is me right [now](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/22696597.jpg).

What I need is a fresh perspective and assistance. Am I making this too hard?

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make sense.  The dates change, for instance, so new values appear that aren't in the original table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery along with [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and the modulo operator:

```
select
    ID,
    Purpose,
    Date,
    case when rownum % 2 = 0 then 1 else -1 end as Val
from (
    SELECT 
        ID 
        ,Purpose 
        ,Date
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ID) as rownum
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            Purpose,
            Date
        FROM DerpTable WHERE Purpose LIKE '%DERP%' 
        GROUP BY ID, DATE) as HerpTable, DerpTable 
        WHERE HerpTable.ID = DerpTable.ID AND DerpTable.ID = HerpTable.ID
) [t1]
```

`ROW_NUMBER` will assign a value to each row, in this case it's an incrementing value. Using the modulus with 2 allows us to check if it's even or odd and assign `1` or `-1`.

Note: I don't know if this query will run since I don't know the architecture of your database, but the idea should get you there.

Comment: My problem is that I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. It is telling me that FIRST_VALUE and FIRST is not recognized as a built-in function name. I know your query is right, but as I indicated in my question, FIRST doesn't work for me. The key part figuring out how to get FIRST(purpose) when I'm not given much to go off.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your problem. Your question says you are trying to get an alternating `1`/`-1` pattern, which is what my example does. Why do you need `First`?

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I want, 1/-1. I updated my question to read better. I thought your question contained the FIRST function, but don't see it anymore. Last quest and I won't bother you anymore. How can I make a view and join this column of 1 and -1 to the original data? I don't care what the value is if the purpose is not derp. Make that 0? God sql is hard.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `first_value()` in SQL Server 2012.  I'm not sure what the `WHERE` condition is in your query, but the following should return your desired results:

```
  SELECT ID,
         FIRST_VALUE(Purpose) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) as Purpose,
         DATE,
         2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) - 1
  FROM DERPTABLE
```

Comment: I gave + rep for your comment. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an incremental column, update the table using modulo to determine if it's even or odd, then drop the column?

Comment: I'm sorry? This is a solution to his problem. I might have worded it as a question, but this is pseudo code that leads to what he wants.

Comment: It's not pseudocode, it's an idea for part of the solution, written  as normal text.  Not criticising, just saying :)

Comment: I gave + rep for your reply.

Comment: That comment was in reply to a snarky comment and a downvote from the selected answer's poster. We apparently have differing opinions on how SO should be helping people with their problems.